# Creating 8 byte character array

Tags: c#

Sometimes I get a value "0001" and sometimes "10001000". I try to convert this to array of characters using code like so:

`var array = ConvertToBinary(0x128.toString(“X”).ToCharArray();`

then I use it like so:

`x[6] = value[6];`

My problem happens when I get "0001" only since the index will not reach 6. So I get index out of range exception. This is my `ConverToBinary` function:

```
private static string ConvertToBinary(string hexString)
{
    return String.Join(String.Empty, hexString.Select(
        c => Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString(), 16), 2).PadLeft(4, '0')
        )
    );
}
```

If I change the .PadLeft(4, '0') to .PadLeft(8, '0') and my value = "10001000" instead of 8 bytes, I get 16 bytes

Comment: Additionally, please provide more context - you talk about values such as "0001" and "10001000" but until the `ConvertToBinary` method, we had no idea that this was meant to be hex. Why convert `_mRx[5]` to a string of hex if you're then just going to convert it to another form? With more context, we could probably give a much simpler solution to the underlying task. (What is `_mRx`, and what are you trying to do with it?)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just copied it from my code. Originally the ‘value’ is a hex so I need to convert it to binary then add 0s to it.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the underlying question of what you're trying to achieve. Starting with an integer, converting it to hex and then converting that to binary sounds like a very long-winded way of finding out whether a specific bit is set. What is `x` here? What's the bigger context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hexadecimal conversion is off. It considers each character separately, giving you `15` for `F` and `1515` for `FF`.

Convert the hexadecimal string as a whole:

```
private static string ConvertToBinary(string hexString)
{
    return Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(hexString, 16), 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
}
```